# input mask not working with underscore templates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to use http://www.angelwatt.com/coding/masked_input.php#nav-example to change the way my input handle dates. It works great with bootstrap and jquery but
when I place my input fields inside a jscript template, it does not work.

```
This works
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="some-mask" placeholder="" value="" />

<script type="text/template" id="tpl">
This doesnt work
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="some-mask2" placeholder="" value="" />
</script>       

<script type="text/javascript">
MaskedInput({
                  elm: document.getElementById('some-mask'),

                  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                  separator: '\/',
                  typeon: 'DMY'
            });
    MaskedInput({
                  elm: document.getElementById('some-mask2'),

                  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                  separator: '\/',
                  typeon: 'DMY'
            });     
</script>
```

Anyone know any clues as to why it doesnt work? Thank you.

Comment: Where did you use the `tpl` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you run this:

```
MaskedInput({
    elm: document.getElementById('some-mask2'),
    //...
});
```

there is no `#some-mask2` to be found so you're really saying `elm: null`. Your `#some-mask2` element is inside the `#tpl` template but that template is not HTML and is not in the DOM until you compile it, fill it in, and put it somewhere on the page.

Somewhere you have something structured like this:

```
var t = _.template($('#tpl').html());
var h = t({...});
$(something).append(h);
```

You want to call `MaskedInput` *after* your equivalent of the above has put the filled in template in the DOM.